# C++ shared pointer wrapper for lazy initialization

Tags: c++, c++17, pointers, lazy

I have written a very simple wrapper around `std::shared_ptr` that supports lazy initialization. Do you see any problems?

```
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <class T, typename ... Args>
class LazySharedPtr {
public:
    LazySharedPtr(Args ... args) :
        ptr(nullptr) {
        this->init = [args = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args) ...)]() mutable {
            return std::apply([](auto&& ... args) {
                return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
                }, std::move(args));
        };
    }

    virtual ~LazySharedPtr() = default;

    bool IsInited() const noexcept {
        return ptr != nullptr;
    }

    void Init() {
        this->InitAndGet();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> Get() {
        return (ptr) ? ptr : InitAndGet();
    }

    const std::shared_ptr<T> Get() const {
        return (ptr) ? ptr : InitAndGet();      
    }

    T* operator ->() {
        return this->Get().get();
    }

    const T* operator ->() const {
        return this->Get().get();
    }

    explicit operator bool() const noexcept {
        return this->IsInited();
    }

protected:
    std::function<std::shared_ptr<T>()> init;
    mutable std::shared_ptr<T> ptr;

    std::shared_ptr<T> InitAndGet() const {
        ptr = this->init();
        return ptr;
    }
};
```

*Note:* Visual Studio report warning for `this->Get().get()`:

> Warning   C26815  The pointer is dangling because it points at a
> temporary instance which was destroyed.

However, I dont see why, because shared_ptr is owned by the class so there should alway be at least one instance "alive". Imho, This warning is not reported by compiler, only by Intellisense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A really useful idea - well worth creating.

Missing `#include <memory>`.  With that fixed, I get almost clean compilation:

```
255367.cpp:9:5: warning: ‘LazySharedPtr<int, int>::init’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
```

I agree, we should use the initialisation list for `init`:

```
LazySharedPtr(Args ... args)
    : init{[args = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args) ...)]() mutable
           {
               return std::apply([](auto&& ... args) {
                                     return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
                                 }, std::move(args));
           }},
      ptr{}
{}
```

I don't see why we have the inner lambda.  There's no good reason not to pass `std::make_shared()` directly to `std::apply()`, like this:

```
LazySharedPtr(Args ... args)
    : init{[args = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args) ...)]() mutable
           {
               return std::apply(std::make_shared<T, Args...>, std::move(args));
           }},
      ptr{}
{}
```

Finally here, `std::forward()` is the wrong function to use on `args`, which is not a forwarding reference.  Use `std::move()`, since we take the arguments by value.

---

I think the class could be easier to use.  There's no need for the argument types to be part of the class itself, as they are erased by `std::function`.  So make the class template have only `T` as argument.  Otherwise we need separate code paths for our smart pointers if they are created differently.  Much better to separate the type that is *essential* to the `LazySharedPtr` from those which are *accidental*:

```
template <class T>
class LazySharedPtr {
public:
    template <typename ... Args>
    LazySharedPtr(Args ... args);
}
```

There's some functionality missing that I would expect from a drop-in replacement for `std::shared_ptr`:

- `operator*`
- `get()`
- `reset()`

I'd also expect a `LazySharedPtr` to be assignable to `std::shared_ptr` (invoking the creator function in the process).  That could reduce the need for these functions (especially `reset()`, which might not make sense here).

On the other hand, I don't think that `LazySharedPtr` is intended as a base class for inheritance, so shouldn't need a virtual destructor.  And we don't need `IsInited()`, given we already have `operator bool`.

Do have a think about what it means to *copy* a lazy-pointer object.  As it stands, copying a materialized instance yields another shared pointer to the same `T` object, but copying an unmaterialized instance will result in different `T` objects in the original and the copy.  I wonder if this could make it difficult to use correctly; we might want to make this a move-only type, and require casting to `std::shared_ptr` in order to copy (thus materialising the object).

For efficiency, `InitAndGet()` shouldn't copy the shared pointer, but return a reference.  I'm not fond of the naming - C++ convention uses `snake_case` for function names.

There's a lot of unnecessary `this->` cluttering the code.

---

## Modified code

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <class T>
class LazySharedPtr {
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    LazySharedPtr(Args... args)
        : ptr{},
          init{[args = std::make_tuple(std::move(args)...)]() mutable
               { return std::apply(std::make_shared<T, Args...>, std::move(args)); }}
    {}

    // compiler-defaulted copy/move construct and assign, and destructor

    auto operator->() const
    { return object().get(); }

    auto operator*() const
    { return *object(); }

    auto operator[](std::ptrdiff_t idx)
    { return object()[idx]; }

    explicit operator bool() const noexcept
    { return ptr; }

    explicit operator std::shared_ptr<T>() const
    { return object(); }

private:
    mutable std::shared_ptr<T> ptr;
    std::function<std::shared_ptr<T>()> init;

    auto& object() const
    {
        if (!ptr) { ptr = init(); }
        return ptr;
    }
};


int main()
{
    LazySharedPtr<int> a{0};
    auto b = std::shared_ptr<int>{a};
    return *b;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't we return a reference from `operator*` instead of a pointer? Also `std::shared_ptr::get()` is a `const` function that returns a non-`const` pointer, so I think we can get away with only a single function for both the dereference and arrow operators: `T& operator*() const` and `T* operator->() const`. (Well, I guess `ptr` is mutable so we could do that anyway...)

Comment: Yeah, there’s a bit of `const` confusion here. For a (smart) pointer that’s `const`, `operator->` should return `T* const`… not `T const*`… and the `const` in `T* const` is specious on a return type, so basically `operator->() const` should return `T*`. But I think that’s all moot, because a lazy type should’t support `const` member functions at all (even with `operator bool`… what exactly of the semantics of that supposed to be? `IsInited` was a more logical name). If you want a `const` pointer, cast it to `std::shared_ptr`; but `LazySharedPtr` shouldn’t support being `const` at all.

Comment: Also, the `std::forward` in the constructor is really misleading. `[args = std::tuple{std::move(args)...}]` is *much* clearer about what’s going on. (And shorter!)

Comment: Yes, I rushed the `operator*()` and friends.  That's not the meat of the review, though, and I'm sure that's easily corrected.

Comment: If you want a move-only class that creates a `shared_ptr` when materialized, wouldn’t that be a `LazyUniquePtr` that can be converted to either a `unique_ptr` or `ahared_ptr`, materializing it?

Comment: @Davislor, that makes perfect sense; I don't know why I didn't see that.  It helps that a unique pointer is easily convertible to shared, too.